# ObjectForKey always returns null xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have tried to set string into the cache using NSCache in Xamarin.iOS setting id done without problem, but when tries to get this cached value always return null, any one can help, please?

```
/*set*/
public static void AddCachedString(NSString key, NSString Value)
{
    cacheProvider.SetObjectforKey(key, Value);
}

/*get*/
public static NSString GetCachedString(NSString key)
{
     return (NSString)cacheProvider.ObjectForKey(key);
}
```

Comment: Have you solved your issues?

Comment: I have tried another way to save and get values data from cache using NSUserDefaults  and i used its 2 methods set& get, and it work properly. 
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Your device brings proper output to me thanks again.

Comment: Then can you mark and close this post to help other community understand NSCache？

Comment: How can i mark and close the post, please?

Comment: Just click the gray tick left beside the answer.

Comment: ok, i made it, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `public virtual void SetObjectforKey(NSObject obj, NSObject key);` has two parameters value and key, you just made a mistake in the order. The second parameter is the key.

You should modify your own method like:

```
cacheProvider.SetObjectforKey(Value, key);
```

In this way you can get this value with the correct key string. Moreover please pay attention to the [Apple Documentation NSCache](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscache):

> You typically use NSCache objects to temporarily store objects with
>   transient data that are expensive to create. However, the objects are not critical to the application and can be discarded if memory is tight.

If you want to persists the data, you can try [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Foundation.NSUserDefaults/).